# Replacing characters in article filenames (URL) when creating/updating

Tags: publishing-page

We want to change some special characters from the final URL when new articles are created or updated.
For instance "Hello æøå world" would look like "Hello%20%C3%A6%C3%B8%C3%A5%20world", but we want it to instead look like "Hello-aeoa-world".
Keeping the original title is also important.

**Update:**
Have tried doing this:

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdated(properties);
    SPFile file = properties.ListItem.File;
    String url = file.Url.Replace(“ø”, “o”);
    EventFiringEnabled = false;
    if (file.Exists && !url.Equals(file.Url))
    {
        file.MoveTo(url, true);
        file.Update();
    }
    EventFiringEnabled = true;
}
```

This will move the file properly.
But since this is run after everything is complete there might not be any more updates, and the user is redirected to the old URL, which will result in a 404.

Using `ItemAdding` does not help since ListItem is not created, and properties.AfterProperties does not work.
At least not any of these (testing with title):

```
properties.AfterProperties["Title"]= "Test";
properties.AfterProperties["Tittel"]= "Test";
properties.AfterProperties["vti_title"]= "Test";
properties.AfterProperties[SPBuiltInFields.Title.ToString()]= "Test";
```

And `properties.BeforeUrl` and `properties.AfterUrl` can not be assigned to.

If I move the file in `ItemAdded` there seems to be some lost connection between `properties.ListItem` and `properties.ListItem.File` since the file is moved, but page layout is set to nothing (as well as content type and every other property) so it prints an error.

**Update 2:**
properties.AfterProperties works if I do exactly this:

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
        properties.AfterProperties["vti_title"] = "test";
}
```

But this changes the title, not the URL. I want to change the URL and keep the title.